# How to get application ID (GUID) in simulator directory (XCode 5)

Tags: ios, xcode

How do I get AppID as below:

```
  (/Users/**USERNAME**/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/**APPID**/Documents)
```

if I write a script in Build Phases? Is there a special environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it can be obtained directly, but you can get it from
`[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]` or getting the path for `NSDocumentDirectory` .

Comment: No, it is for Objective-C. I write build script (for sh shell) [link](http://www.runscriptbuildphase.com).